# Create a doctrine repository with dependencies (dependency injection) in ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dependency-injection, zend-framework2, doctrine

I want to make a repository with hard dependencies. I found **[this blog post by Jurian Sluisman](https://juriansluiman.nl/article/142/dependency-injection-in-a-doctrine-repository)** but he suggests getting the repository from the service manager and injecting it into the service where needed.

It would be much better if I would be able to get my custom repositories with injected dependencies like normally from my `EntityManager` or `ObjectManager` instance by using the `getRepository` method:

```
$objectManager->getRepository('My\Entity\Class');
```

How can I use constructor injection in my Repositories and still get them like normally from the `ObjectManager` directly with the `getRepository` method?

Comment: Which container are you using?  The Symfony container handles this directly.  I suspect you are using the ZF container?

Comment: @Cerad yes, I am working with Zend Framework 2

Comment: Excellent question. Answer as I needed it. Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doctrine uses [a factory class `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface\DefaultRepositoryFactory`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php) for creating repository instances. If no custom factory is set this default factory is created [here in the `getRepositoryFactory` method](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php#L816) in [the `Doctrine\ORM\Configuration` class](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php).

By defining a custom `repository_factory` we can overwrite this default factory class and add custom logic to the factory that will inject the hard dependencies:

To illustrate how you can do this I will show an example where the repository factory class creates repositories that are dependent on a `ServiceLocator` instance through constructor injection.

**1) make a custom factory class that implements the doctrine `RepositoryFactory` interface**

*This class looks very similar to the doctrine `DefaultRepositoryFactory`* class.

```
<?php

namespace My\ORM\Repository;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository;    
use Doctrine\ORM\Repository\RepositoryFactory;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class CustomRepositoryFactory implements RepositoryFactory, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

    /**
     * @var ObjectRepository[]
     */
    private $repositoryList = array();

    /**
     * @var ServiceLocator
     */
    protected $serviceLocator;

    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     */
    public function __construct(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getRepository(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityName)
    {
        $repositoryHash = $entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityName)->getName() . spl_object_hash($entityManager);

        if (isset($this->repositoryList[$repositoryHash])) {
            return $this->repositoryList[$repositoryHash];
        }

        return $this->repositoryList[$repositoryHash] = $this->createRepository($entityManager, $entityName);
    }

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager The EntityManager instance.
     * @param string                 $entityName    The name of the entity.
     * @return ObjectRepository
     */
    private function createRepository(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityName)
    {
        /* @var $metadata \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata */
        $metadata            = $entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityName);
        $repositoryClassName = $metadata->customRepositoryClassName
            ?: $entityManager->getConfiguration()->getDefaultRepositoryClassName();

        // Constructor injection, I check with subclass of but it is just an example
        if(is_subclass_of($repositoryClassName, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface::class)){
            $serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator()
            $repository = new $repositoryClassName($entityManager, $metadata, $serviceLocator);
        }else{
            $repository = new $repositoryClassName($entityManager, $metadata);
        }
        return $repository;
    }
}
```

**2) Create a factory for the repository factory**

```
<?php
namespace My\ORM\Repository\Factory;

use My\ORM\Repository\CustomRepositoryFactory;
use Zend\Cache\Storage\StorageInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class CustomRepositoryFactoryFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return StorageInterface
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new CustomRepositoryFactory($serviceLocator);
    }
}
```

**3) register the factory for the repository factory in the `service_manager` config**

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'My\ORM\Repository\CustomRepositoryFactory' => 'My\ORM\Repository\Factory\CustomRepositoryFactoryFactory'
    )
)
```

**4) register the repository factory in the doctrine config**

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'repository_factory' => 'My\ORM\Repository\CustomRepositoryFactory'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: +1 This is the way I've done it as well; I think Jurian's blog post was written when Doctrine hard coded the creation of the default repository within the entity manager.

Comment: You use 'DefaultRepositoryFactory' throughout your answer, but then specify 'CustomRepositoryFactory' in step 3.  Is this a copy/paste error?  Or is there a reason for that?  I'm trying to follow through assuming you meant 'Default' but I'm getting a bunch of errors and I'm not sure where 'Custom' is coming from.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated after @d.lanza38 his comment (better late then never).