# How can i inject class inside custom repository - Symfony 2.7

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex

I have custom repository class in which i must inject class that helps me to upload file, and erase file if needed. I expanded EntityRepository constructor, but i don't know how to add third argument inside custom repository class.

```
    class NewRepository extends EntityRepository
    {

        protected $fileUploader;



        public function __construct(EntityManager $em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class,FileUploader $fileUploader)
        {
            parent::__construct($em, $class);
        }

        public function create($data, Item $item = null)
        {
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            if(!$item) $item = new Item();

            if(isset($data['file'])) {
                $image = $this->fileUploader->setFile($data['file'])->uploadFile();
                $data['filename'] = $image['filename'];
                $data['image_url'] = $image['file_url'];
            }

            $item->setTitle($data['title']);
            $item->setDescription($data['description']);

            $em->persist($item);
            $em->flush($item);

            return $item;
        }

    }
```

I always get error that third argument passed to constructor is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a doctrine repository with dependencies (dependency injection) in ZF2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33630909/create-a-doctrine-repository-with-dependencies-dependency-injection-in-zf2)

Comment: how do you instantiate your custom repository ?

Comment: You will need to define the repository as a service and add a setUploader method.  Stackoverflow has a few hundred examples showing how.

Comment: @Cerad `setUploader` is not required here. It can be a constructor argument, as it is now.

Comment: @JakubMatczak The only way to create a doctrine repository is using DoctrineEntityManager::getRepository();  You cannot new it directly.  And internally there is a static create method for creating a new repository.  So unless you want to extend the entity manager and then clone a fairly complicated static method, you do indeed need to use setter injection.

Comment: @Cerad Oh, you're right, my mistake. It's not possible in case of repository.

Comment: @Cerad setter injection is not really good, especially Doctrine has [RepositoryFactory](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php) you can easily write on your own and was implemented specifically to allow injecting additional dependencies into repositories

Comment: @malarzm - Interesting.  Considering that the question was tagged with Symfony, please consider posting an answer showing a custom repository factory as well as how to integrate it into Symfony.  Using setter injection is trivial and poses no problem for this use case but it would be good to see an example of your approach.  The only examples I could find involved a fair amount of compiler pass code.

Comment: @Cerad here you go!

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.4 Doctrine uses a [`RepositoryFactory`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/ee066cc5de7e8726d0be7a2d241235ba6c033cf8/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/RepositoryFactory.php) for instantiating repositories and as a starter provides you with [`DefaultRepositoryFactory`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/ee066cc5de7e8726d0be7a2d241235ba6c033cf8/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php). To be able to inject additional dependencies into your repositories you need to roll your own implementation of aforementioned factory (I'm omitting all the `use` statements for brevity):

```
class YourRepositoryFactory implements RepositoryFactory
{
    private $fileUploader;

    public function __construct(FileUploader $fileUploader)
    {
        $this->fileUploader = $fileUploader;
    }

    public function getRepository(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityName)
    {
        $repositoryHash = $entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityName)->getName() . spl_object_hash($entityManager);
        if (isset($this->repositoryList[$repositoryHash])) {
            return $this->repositoryList[$repositoryHash];
        }
        return $this->repositoryList[$repositoryHash] = $this->createRepository($entityManager, $entityName);
    }

    private function createRepository(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityName)
    {
        /* @var $metadata \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata */
        $metadata            = $entityManager->getClassMetadata($entityName);
        $repositoryClassName = $metadata->customRepositoryClassName
            ?: $entityManager->getConfiguration()->getDefaultRepositoryClassName();

        switch ($repositoryClassName) {
            case NewRepository::class:
                return new $repositoryClassName($entityManager, $metadata, $this->fileUploader);
            default:
                return new $repositoryClassName($entityManager, $metadata);
        }
    }
}
```

After registering your factory as a service in the way you prefer you need to adjust `doctrine` configuration with:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        repository_factory: name.of.your.factory.service
```

And you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting that repository_factory is documented here http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html but not here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html