# autowiring to reduce list of services

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine

In a multi-tenanted system, I'm injecting the current users role into all my Doctrine repositories to ensure users can only see what they have access to:

```
class SiteRepository extends SecurityAwareRepository
{
    public function createQueryBuilder($alias, $indexBy = null)
    {
        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
                        ->select($alias)
                        ->from($this->_entityName, $alias, $indexBy)
                        ->orderBy("$alias.name");

        switch ($this->getHighestRole()) {
            case 'ROLE_PARTNER':
                $qb
                    ->innerJoin("$alias.BilledTo", 'o')
                    ->innerJoin('o.Users', 'u')
                    ->where('u.id=:user_id')
                    ->setParameter('user_id', $this->getUserId())
                ;
                break;
            case 'ROLE_CUSTOMER':
                $qb
                    ->innerJoin("$alias.Organisation", 'o')
                    ->innerJoin('o.Users', 'u')
                    ->where('u.id=:user_id')
                    ->setParameter('user_id', $this->getUserId())
                ;
                break;
            case 'ROLE_SUPERADMIN':
                //full access
                break;
            default:
                $qb->where('1=0');

        }
        return $qb;
    }
```

I'm currently loading these repositories as services like this:

```
services:
    invoice_repository:
        class: AppBundle\Repository\InvoiceRepository
        factory: ["@doctrine", getRepository]
        arguments:
            - "AppBundle:Invoice"
        calls:
          - method: setTokenStorage
            arguments:
              - "@security.token_storage"
    site_repository:
        class: AppBundle\Repository\SiteRepository
        factory: ["@doctrine", getRepository]
        arguments:
            - "AppBundle:Site"
        calls:
          - method: setTokenStorage
            arguments:
              - "@security.token_storage"
```

can I eliminate this repetition with auto-wiring, and if yes how?

Comment: While not related to autowire, you can actually plugin your own RepositoryFactory class which in turn can take care of injecting the token storage for you.  Eliminates the calls portion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008937/how-can-i-inject-class-inside-custom-repository-symfony-2-7/44070750#44070750  Using your own factory is conceptually a bit better because it allows $em->getRepo to work as expected.

Comment: Another approach to avoiding the calls sections is to use a parent service. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html

Comment: Cerad, I implemented a custom repository factory, can you add this as an answer I can accept?

Comment: Appreciate it but just go ahead and up vote the linked answer and we will call it good.

Answer (score 2):

## Up until recently

For a while, I used a trait and wired the setter injection like in your example, which was fairly repetitive.

Then, I started using the improved autowiring in 3.3 to help wire my repositories like so:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    ...... redacted stuff ......

    Entity\PageRepository:
        public: true
        factory: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', getRepository]
        arguments: [Entity\Page]
```

Inside `PageRepository`, I use a trait like below:

```
trait AppContextTrait
{
    protected $appContext;

    /**
     * @required
     */
    public function setAppContext(AppContext $appContext)
    {
        $this->appContext = $appContext;
    }

    public function getAppContext(): AppContext
    {
        return $this->appContext;
    }
}
```

The `@required` annotation tells the autowirer to call methods when the class is instantiated.

I actually have very little DIC configuration now with everything being fully autowired, with the exception of repositories. There was still a lot of repetition in the repositories' DIC config.

## But now,

After I read [Magnus Nordlander's blog post about autowiring repositories](https://blog.fervo.se/blog/2017/07/06/doctrine-repositories-autowiring/), I've started setting up my repositories similar to Magnus's example below. It avoids the closed entity-manager problem, and it lets autowiring take care of the DIC config. Now my DIC config files are extremely slim! :)

```
class UserRepository
{
    private $managerRegistry;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
    }

    public function find($id): ?User
    {
        return $this->getManager()->find(User::class, $id);
    }

    public function findOneUsingACustomQuery($parameter): ?User
    {
        return $this->getManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from(User::class, 'u')
            ->where('u.something = :param')
            ->setParameter('param', $parameter)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
            ->getSingleResult();
    }

    protected function getManager(): \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    {
        return $this->managerRegistry->getManagerForClass(User::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good answer as well and I had seen that post. But haven't chosen this at this point because I'm not clear what the issues were he ran into with his PR. Would love to learn more